# Speech Recognition with MediaRecorder - Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, mediarecorder

I am making an app in which I am recording a video and at the same time want to implement a speech-to-text recognition functionality without speech dialog, can someone tell me how to proceed.

Comment: concurrent recorder and recognizer in a project : https://github.com/rowntreerob/Google-speech-Opus-Recorder

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the RecognizerIntent Class. The class sends the recorded speech to a Google cloud server. The server in turn converts the speech to text and sends the results to your app.

A worked out example can be found on the following site
[right here](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/).

Using this approach however does imply that your app will rely having a working internet connection. Only if the user decides to enable offline voice typing in the phone's settings, won't the app be relying on a working internet connection.

Comment: i did the same but every time a record a video and use speech recognition i get SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK

Comment: That might be because you forgot to add any permissions to your android manifest files to access the internet?

Comment: Could you give us more information, perhaps post the code that you've worked on?

Comment: The `RecognizerIntent` Video+STT approach will work on some devices/firmwares (e.g. Pixel, Xiaomi, Oppo) but won't work on some others (e.g. Samsung S10). I'm currently facing this problem.

Comment: @stone did you find a way to make it work on samsung s10? 
Also, is there any documentation or resource that can tell us which devices are supported and which are not?